# Change FormControl value from ControlValueAccessor

Tags: angular, typescript, controlvalueaccessor

I am trying to create a directive for case only. I created the following code but I have a problem trying to make formGroup.value.
The directive changes the value visually (by using _Renderer2), but the formControl still has the original value and when obtaining the data from the form with formGroup.value, the values are in lowercase. Is it possible to fix that? Thank you

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
    <mat-form-field>
        <input placeholder="Street" formControlName="streetName" matInput uppercase>
    </mat-form-field>
</form>

import { Directive, ElementRef, Optional, Renderer2, Self } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NgControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: "textarea[uppercase], input[uppercase]",
  host: {
    '(input)': 'writeValue($event.target.value)',
    '(blur)': 'onTouched()',
  }
})
export class UppercaseDirective implements ControlValueAccessor {

  onChange = (_: any) => {
    console.log("onChange", _)
  };

  onTouched = () => {
    console.log("onTouched")
  };

  constructor(private _renderer: Renderer2, private _elementRef: ElementRef, @Optional() @Self() public ngControl: NgControl) {
    ngControl.valueAccessor = this;
  }

  writeValue(value: any): void {
    this._renderer.setProperty(this._elementRef.nativeElement, 'value', this.transformValue(value));
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: (_: any) => {}): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: () => {}): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

  setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    this._renderer.setProperty(this._elementRef.nativeElement, 'disabled', isDisabled);
  }

  private transformValue(value: string): string {
    return typeof value === 'string'
      ? value?.toUpperCase()
      : value;
  }
}
```

Comment: That make sense, your changing the DOM so angular not recognizing this.
Im not sure how to help you since its been like 9 months since I last used angular, but I think your gonna need to try and get the "form control" itself

Comment: Directives only change what we see in the DOM, they don't actually change the value itself.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing the concepts of custom form control and directive. I don't know if there are another aproach, but, if you want to make a directive that transform one input, you can get it creating a HTMLEvent. Some like

```
@Directive({
  selector: "[toUpperCase]"
})
export class ToUpperCaseDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {}

  @HostListener("input", ["$event"]) onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    this.setUpper();
  }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setUpper();
    });
  }
  setUpper() {
    const target = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
    let pos = target.selectionStart; //get the position of the cursor
    target.value = target.value.toUpperCase();
    var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
    evt.initEvent("input", false, true);
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(evt);
    target.selectionStart = target.selectionEnd = pos; //return the position
  }
}
```

NOTE: Really I don't see the directive as a good aproach to the problem on upperCase an input. For me is better simply use css

```
<input style="text-transform:uppercase">
```

Then, when we want to check the value transform the value use toUpperCase.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Doing it using CSS is useless for me, because it is just a visual change, when I get the data from formgroup.value, it is lowercase. I will test your directive